# Escape string from file

Tags: c#

I have to parse some files that contain some string that has characters in them that I need to escape. To make a short example you can imagine something like this:

```
        var stringFromFile = "This is \\n a test \\u0085";
        Console.WriteLine(stringFromFile);
```

The above results in the output:

```
        This is \n a test \u0085
```

, but I want the text escaped. How do I do this in C#? The text contains unicode characters too.

**To make clear; The above code is just an example. The text contains the \n and unicode \u00xx characters from the file.**

Example of the file contents:

> Fisika (vanaf Grieks, \u03C6\u03C5\u03C3\u03B9\u03BA\u03CC\u03C2,
>   \"Natuurlik\", en \u03C6\u03CD\u03C3\u03B9\u03C2, \"Natuur\") is die
>   wetenskap van die Natuur

Comment: See my answer, Regex.Unescape should be the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it using: `Regex.Unescape(string)`

Should be the right way.

Att.

Comment: [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx) make it seem partial at best. It only serves to strip out regex codes, not actually translate escapes to characters.

Comment: `Fisika (vanaf Grieks, \u03C6\u03C5\u03C3\u03B9\u03BA\u03CC\u03C2, \"Natuurlik\", en \u03C6\u03CD\u03C3\u03B9\u03C2, \"Natuur\") is die wetenskap van die Natuur`

Turns into:

`Fisika (vanaf Grieks, φυσικός, "Natuurlik", en φύσις, "Natuur") is die wetenskap van die Natuur`

Comment: This works great, also takes care of those unicode's. Thanks!

Comment: Ah you beat me to the punch. +1 for you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the `@` symbol -- this interprets the string as 100% literal. Just take it off and all shall be well.

**EDIT**

I may have been a bit hasty with my reply. I think what you're asking is: how can I have C# turn the literal string '\n' into a newline, when read from a file (similar question for other escaped literals).

The answer is: you write it yourself. You need to search for "\\n" and convert it to "\n". Keep in mind that in C#, it's the *compiler* not the *language* that changes your strings into actual literals, so there's not some library call to do this (actually there could be -- someone look this up, quick).

**EDIT**

Aha! Eureka! Behold:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx

Comment: This is just an example, as I said. The text comes with the \n and \u00** characters from the file. The above is just an example.

Comment: I'm from Canada. They say I'm slow, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the string from a file, \n is not read as a unicode character but rather as two characters \ and n.

I would say you probably need a search an replace function to convert string "\n" to its unicode character '\n'  and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any easy way to do this. Because it's the job of lexical analyzer to parse literals.

I would try generating and compiling a class via CodeDOM with the string inserted there as constant. It's not very fast but it will do all escaping.